# Trigger for INSERT to validate input data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

My problem:

table `dbo.student` has `StudentID` like `SV001`.

How can I create a trigger to check data inserted into `dbo.student` has a `StudentID` that begins with `SV` and the numbers in the range 000 to 100?

Example: `SV099` is valid id to insert, while `SV101` is not valid

Comment: Read the tutorials and documentation on triggers, start writing one, and test it against your requirements. Ask a question when stuck.

Comment: In the documentation look at the [string functions section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I tried create trigger before, sorry for not post my idea . Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL constraints:

```
CHECK (CAST(SUBSTRING(StudentID, 3, LEN(StudentID)) AS int) <= 100)
```

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE tb
( 
    StudentID varchar(10) 
        CHECK (CAST(SUBSTRING(StudentID, 3, LEN(StudentID)) AS int) <= 100)
);

// test data
INSERT INTO tb VALUES ('sv000');  //valid
INSERT INTO tb VALUES ('sv100');  //valid

INSERT INTO tb VALUES ('sv101');  //invalid
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=26288b52f768e4a431135744019ce8c0)

Or if you want to use a trigger:

**Note**: you must use the `inserted` keyword to access the record that has just been added

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerStudentID
ON tb
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StudentID varchar(10);

    SET @StudentID = (SELECT TOP 1 StudentID FROM inserted);

    IF (CAST(SUBSTRING(@StudentID, 3, LEN(@StudentID)) AS int) > 100)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=9c567992b7632fe9ff4b5ea28d794bec).

Or you can use the following trigger

```
Create Trigger TriggerStudentID
On tb
AFTER INSERT 
As
Begin
   Declare @StudentID varchar(10);
   DECLARE my_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT StudentID FROM INSERTED; 
   OPEN my_Cursor; 
        
     
   FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor INTO @StudentID;
        
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
   BEGIN
        
   FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor INTO @StudentID;
   If (CAST(SUBSTRING(@StudentID,3,LEN(@StudentID)) AS int) > 100)
       RollBack Transaction
        
   END
   CLOSE my_Cursor; 
   DEALLOCATE my_Cursor;
 END
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a67d97c140c93202c07dd10aaa6543ad).

Comment: what about condition StudentID starting with 'SV'? Can i use:  NOT LIKE 'SV%'. I tried: If (CAST(SUBSTRING(@StudentID,3,LEN(@StudentID)) AS int) > 100 AND @StudentID NOT LIKE 'SV%') but it not working.

Comment: I should use OR instead of AND. it worked. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @marc_s Take a look at this link to see if there is a problem https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=39a0acfc14992479a699b5f457058ee5

Comment: Cursor option is also not working properly in above solution. when we use two insert statements at once (very first query in your sample) and  first one fails, then second will never proceed. Eg. insert into tb values('sv202');
insert into tb values('sv053');
SV053 will not be inserted. In your sample you are inserting SV053 first, so it works, but try to insert SV202 first and SV053 at second, SV053 will never be inserted